# Yii validation with file upload failing

Tags: validation, file-upload, yii

I'm having what looks to me some strange behaviour within Yii.

I have a simple file upload, that takes a `name` and the file itself.

If I just submit the form with no name or file I can bypass the validation (i.e - My controller action is called and is trying to process the uploaded file) I think my rules() are setup accordingly to stop this. These are my relevant rules:

```
public function rules() {
    return array(
        array('name file', 'required', 'message' => 'This field is required'), 
        array('file', 'file', 'on' => 'insert', 'allowEmpty' => false, 'safe'=>true,
            'maxSize'=> 512000, 
            'maxFiles'=> 1, 
            'mimeTypes' => 'application/msword, text/plain',
            'tooLarge'=> 'file cannot be larger than 500KB.',
            'wrongMimeType'=> 'Format must be: .doc .txt'
        ),
```

I specified that the file is required and also within the file array that allowEmpty should be false. So what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance for any help

**Controller**

```
public function actionCreate() {

    $model = new File;

    if (isset($_POST['File'])) {

        $model->setAttributes($_POST['File']);

        // Set file
        $model->file = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'file');

        // Set directory
        $dest = Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.uploads');

        $model->tmp_name = time();
        $model->date_added = new CDbExpression('NOW()');
        $model->file_type = $model->file->type;
        $model->file_size = $model->file->size;
        $model->extension = $model->file->extensionName;


        if ($model->save()) {

            $model->file->saveAs(($dest . '/' . $model->tmp_name . '.' . $model->file->extensionName));

             Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success','<strong>Success!</strong> Your file has been uploaded');


        }
    }

    $this->render('create', array( 'model' => $model));
}
```

Comment: Please also add the controller action code to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me I found that if I validate before I process the uploaded file it worked. Wasn't quite sure why I had to do that as I thought the save() method automatically called the validate() method

`Validation will be performed before saving the record. If the validation fails, the record will not be saved. You can call getErrors() to retrieve the validation errors.`

**Updated code**

```
public function actionCreate() {

    $model = new File;

    if (isset($_POST['File'])) {

        $model->setAttributes($_POST['File']);

    if($model->validate()){ // add in validation call

        // Set file
        $model->file = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'file');

        // Set directory
        $dest = Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.uploads');

        $model->tmp_name = time();
        $model->date_added = new CDbExpression('NOW()');
        $model->file_type = $model->file->type;
        $model->file_size = $model->file->size;
        $model->extension = $model->file->extensionName;


        if ($model->save()) {

            $model->file->saveAs(($dest . '/' . $model->tmp_name . '.' . $model->file->extensionName));

             Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success','<strong>Success!</strong> Your file has been uploaded');


            }
        }
    }

    $this->render('create', array( 'model' => $model));
}
```

Hope that helps anyone, thanks to @Michael Härtl too

Answer (score 1):

For one you're missing a `,` in your first rule between `name` and `file`. Then you say:

> I can bypass the validation (i.e - My controller action is called ...

From that i assume you use AJAX validation and expect the upload to fail. But you can't do AJAX validation on file uploads with [`CActiveForm`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm).

So if you fix the typo above, you'll at least get AJAX validation for the `name` attribute.

You should maybe also remove the `'on'=>'insert'` scenario. And you don't need the `'safe'=>true` because you don't do massive assignment with the `$model->file` attribute.

Comment: Thanks, I did miss the `,`. No, I actually have 'enableAjaxValidation' => false, for my form. If I add a file to upload and leave the `name` blank and submit, I get an error saying `name` is required. It doesn't happen if I fill the `name` in and leave file filed blank, it just tries to process the form. (updated) controller too) - Thanks

Comment: Hmm. Updated answer. See last 2 sentences.

Comment: Still the same result.