# Yii file upload - filefield not validated

Tags: file, validation, upload, yii

I am kinda new to yii and I'm having problem with file upload.
When I upload a file it doesn't validate - it allows all types (it shouldn't), allows empty (it shouldn't as well) etc. 
Of course I included proper rules (I think) in my model.
It looks like fileField is not validating for some reason.

I want it to write error message (wrong type or empty) when I click on Submit button.
Please take a look at it if you can't find anything wrong.

Here is my form:

```
<?php class UploadSolutionForm extends CFormModel
    {

public $sourceCode;

public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('sourceCode', 'file', 'types'=>'java, zip', 'allowEmpty'=>false, 'wrongType'=>'Only .java and .zip files.'),
    );
}

/**
 * Declares attribute labels.
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return array(
            'sourceCode' => 'Source code',
    );
}}
```

Here is my action in controller:

```
public function actionSolveProblem()
{
    //gets id from url
    $id = Yii::app()->request->getQuery('id');

    //guests can't work with problems in any way
    if (Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
    {
        $this->redirect(array('site/index'));
        return;
    }

    if(isset($id))
    {
        $model = new UploadSolutionForm();

        if(isset($_POST['UploadSolutionForm']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['UploadSolutionForm'];

            $newFile = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'sourceCode');

            $problem = Problems::model()->findByAttributes(array('id'=>$id));

            $version = Solutions::model()->countByAttributes(array('id_problem'=>$id))+1;

            $pathUser = Yii::app()->basePath.'\\SubjectFolder\\'.$problem->id_subject.'\\'.$id.'\\'.Yii::app()->user->getName();

            $path = $pathUser.'\\'.$version;

            if (!is_dir($pathUser)) {
                mkdir($pathUser);
            }
            if (!is_dir($path)) {
                mkdir($path);
            }

            $uploadPath = $path.'\\'.$newFile->name;

            $solution = new Solutions();
            $solution->id_problem = $id;
            $solution->id_user = Yii::app()->user->getId();
            $solution->submit_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time());
            $solution->path_to_file = $uploadPath;
            $solution->version = $version;

            if($newFile->saveAs($uploadPath))
            {
                if($solution->save())
                {
                    Yii::app()->user->setFlash('new_problem','Solution uploaded');
                    $this->redirect(array('site/problems'));
                }
                else
                {
                    Yii::app()->user->setFlash('new_problem','Error! Could not save into db');
                    $this->redirect(array('site/problems'));
                }

            }
        }

        //part bellow is not really important in this case

        $auth = Problems::model()->with(array('subject','subject.currentUserSubject' => array('alias'=>'currentUserSubject')))->findByAttributes(array('id'=>$id));

        // user with proper role cannot upload solutions to problems
        if($auth!=null)
        {
            $this->render('solve',array('model'=>$model));
        }
        else
        {
            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('new_problem','You are not authorized to upload a solution for this problem');
            $this->redirect(array('site/problems'));
        }

    }


}
```

And here is my view (solve.php):

```
<?php 
$form = $this->beginWidget(
        'CActiveForm',
        array(
                'id' => 'upload-form',
                'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
                'enableClientValidation'=>true,
                'clientOptions'=>array(
                        'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
                        ),));
                ?>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'sourceCode');?>
    <br><?php echo $form->fileField($model, 'sourceCode');?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model, 'sourceCode');?>

</div>

<div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Submit'); ?>
    </div>
<?php 
// ...
$this->endWidget();?>
```

I hope sombody can help because I looked all over and I just can't seem to find anything wrong.

EDIT: I mainly want to figure out why client side validation isn't working correctly for file upload (it works for text fields) and of course fix it as well...

Comment: I am having the same issue. This is a link to my question for your reference in case I find out the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17800617/yii-validation-with-file-upload-failing (Sorry this isn't the answer to the problem)

Comment: Your controller code looks weird. Instead of focussing on 1 model and doing proper validation you mess around with 3 different model. So you miss several important steps: You don't assign `$newFile` to `$model->sourceFile`and you don't seem to call `$model->validate()`. Have a look a [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/2/how-to-upload-a-file-using-a-model). All in all: Too much model logic in the controller. You could move a lot of code into the apropriate models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Michael says in the comments, your main issue is that you aren't specifically assigning the upload file to your file attribute in your model. Yii file validations are by default set to unsafe (and as a result, non- mass assignable).

As a result, your uploaded file is never processed by your validation rule.

Comment: Ok, thanks everyone for suggestions. I managed to solve the problem by validating uploaded file in controller, though I wanted to do it client side like text fields...